# How to include spaces in req.body variables

Tags: html, node.js, express, post, body-parser

Let's say I have a variable:

```
var name = "Joe Smith"
```

That I want to include in a POST request via form + option so that I add Joe Smith to my database.

I have already created my form and options and verified that it sends over the name to my controllers/middleware.

I would expect that when I send over the name in the POST request, a call to:

```
req.body.name
```

on the server side would return:

```
Joe Smith
```

However, for some reason white spaces are ignored and req.body.name evaluates to:

```
Joe
```

Similar variables with white spaces in their names/values have this error and as a result I cannot look up these objects in the database and update properly. How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is my script code--I used jQuery to populate options in a select with the names of people in my database

```
$(function() {

  var $people = $("#people");
     $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/getAllPeopleData',
        success: function(people) {
            $.each(people, function(i, person) {
               $people.append('<option value=' + person.name + '>' + 
               person.name + '</option');
              });
            }
         });
     });
```

My form allows the user to select one person's name and adds it to the database:

```
    <form action="/addPerson" method="POST">
        Select a Person: <br>
        <select id="people" name="name"></select> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
    </form?
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can share your html form it can be helpful to answer. I can blindly guess you have to use it in a form as a variable. I should have commented but I'm not yet level 50.

I ran this sample code and it worked:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
 <% var name = 'Joe Smith' %>
 <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= name %>">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the post route, I console logged it out and it came like:

```
POST / 200 1.094 ms - 5
GET / 200 2.202 ms - 352
Joe Smith
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually used jQuery to set options in select tags (see above edit:)

Comment: You should include the snippet with your question too, so people can understand your problem. It's quite hard to understand right now.